# Segoe UI line height is off?

Tags: html, css, fonts, alignment

So, Segoe UI is one of the most popular fonts for websites to use on Windows. I think it looks the best, and other sites like GitHub seem to agree, since they use it as well.

However, there seems to be a problem where the line height is not very accurate, which makes aligning things very hacky. In other cases where fonts are, for example, Arial, there is no issue. Segoe UI seems to be the exception and quite troublesome.

I couldn't find anything related to this on Stackoverflow, but I have found other posts online about this issue. For example, here is [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/26059) struggling with this. [Here's Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1018225) having a similar issue.

I'm not sure of how to solve this. It seems like Segoe UI should be used, as it clearly seems to be the most aesthetic font on Windows by far, but it has this pervasive line height issue that is causing vertical alignment issues.

Currently in my code base I'm trying different approaches (setting line height to 0 in some cases, or 1, or manually adjusting), but none of them seem very consistent in their results.

Has anyone struggled with this issue and found a good workaround?